# Can I get a celery task's arguments if all I have is the task ID?

Tags: python, celery

If I have the original task I can get the arguments from `task.request.args`, but if I only have the task ID is there a way to get the arguments? It doesn't look like there is a way to get them from an `AsyncResult` object, and as far as I can tell there isn't a way to re-create the task.

I want to do this because I have a frontend that polls the backend for updates on tasks, and it would be useful if it could display the task arguments. Seeing as the arguments are stored with the broker, this should be possible, at least when the task is in pending state.

Naturally there are other ways to do this, but it would be a clean way to do things.

Comment: Which version of `Celery` are you using?

Comment: I'm using 4.0.4.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the task is in pending state or if it is executing currently, you can see the arguments of the task. The easiest way is to use celery inspect method.

```
from celery.task.control import inspect
i = inspect()
active_tasks = i.active()
reserved_tasks = i.reserved()
scheduled_tasks = i.scheduled()
```

You can iterate over them and by using task id, you can get all the task details like this

```
{'acknowledged': True,
   'args': '(1000,)',
   'delivery_info': {'exchange': '',
    'priority': 0,
    'redelivered': None,
    'routing_key': 'celery'},
   'hostname': 'celery@pavilion',
   'id': '30d41ba2-3e71-49ce-8e7d-830ba1152256',
   'kwargs': '{}',
   'name': 't.wait',
   'time_start': 1007.945882783,
   'type': 't.wait',
   'worker_pid': 10560}
```

Alterantively, you can also read data from broker, deseriaze it and you can get the task agruments.

Comment: Thank you for the very useful snippet!

Is it possible to do the same for successfully finished jobs?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I am not sure if there is a way to retrieve the same for successfully finished jobs.

Comment: That's would be quite peculiar, since flower is able to display all the succesful tasks with args, kwargs, results, workers etc.

I mean they should be stored somewhere in order for the web interface to be able to retrieve & display them.

Comment: I think flower keeps a cache when a task gets queued and it updates the state once task is completed. If you restart celery, you wont be able to see the past data. You can make celery data persistent by storing them in a db as I have mentioned here https://stackoverflow.com/a/36814141/2698552

Answer (score 0):

For running/pending tasks, you can get the args using:

```
# from celery import Celery 
# app = Celery(. . .)
# assuming app is defined and is object of <Celery>... 


task_result = app.AsyncResult("<id>")
print(task_result.name) # The function name  
print(task_result.args)
print(task_result.kwargs)
```

by default, celery will only return name, args, kwargs for pending/running tasks.

To also get the info for finished tasks, we can add the following config:
https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/userguide/configuration.html#result-extended

```
app = Celery(
    . . .
    result_extended=True,
)
```

p.s: I am not aware about if there are any impacts of this on memory or on DB.  didn't get a chance to do a poc of that.