# How to get arguments passed to the celery's task?

Tags: python, redis, celery

For my web application I use `celery` with `redis` backend. Official [FAQ](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/faq.html#how-do-i-get-the-result-of-a-task-if-i-have-the-id-that-points-there) purposes the following way to acquire the result of a task if I have the ID of the task.

```
result = my_task.AsyncResult(task_id)
result.get()
```

I can easily access arguments within the task body:

```
@app.task
def my_task(foo, bar, baz=None):
    kwargs = self.request.kwargs
    args = self.request.args
```

Is there a way to get `args` and `kwargs` from the AsyncResult or wherever just having the task id?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For new Celery versions you can activate "result_extended" and get args from task object:

```
app.conf.update(
   result_extended=True
)
```

Then, just:

```
print(task.args)
```

Comment: FYI the Celery event type `task-received` says the event dictionary has the `args`: but in practice when i entered the debugger and tried to get the `event['args']` all i got was a short string that was about 80 characters long and only listed the top level fields with `...` in the string and so i could not even do `json.loads` or `eval()`. also FYI the `task-failed` does not have the `args`. --> conclusion use the `result_extended=True`.

Answer (score 3):

If the task is in pending state or if it is executing currently, you can see the arguments of the task [as mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43159483/2698552).

If you want to get the arguments of a failed tasks, you can setup a custom base task with `on_failure` handler to get args when tasks are failed.

```
from celery import Task

class CustomBaseTask(Task):        

    def on_failure(self, exc, task_id, args, kwargs, einfo):
        print(args)

@app.task(base=CustomBaseTask)
def add(x, y):
    raise error
```

On the other hand, if your task is executed successfully, you will have only result and you can't get back your arguments as that information have been consumed and processed by workers from the brokers.

Comment: The problem is that I need these args not just after success/failure of a task, but after e.g. one week, until they became expired in the redis. Now I think it is impossible since celery does not save them to backend

Comment: You can explicitly save args in redis with task id combination.

Comment: @ChillarAnand only when using redis? How about other backends?

Comment: It should work for other backends as well. @user528025